# Multilanguage Home meta description not showing properly on search engine

Tags: magento-1.8, multistore, cms, meta

I have 3 stores, one in Japanese and the others in English.
I have set the meta description for each home CMS page properly. 
However, on the search engine, home meta description is showing the meta description of English home, instead of Japanese home.
But when I check on Firebug, I see the correct meta description in Japanese.

Why...???

Comment: You have different url's?

Comment: yes, I use subdirectory method. 2 english stores contain /en/ and /eu/ in url's.

Comment: When you search your domain, the search engine show you the path with store code (/en/, /eu/, etc)?

Comment: yes it shows, but it's really strange. It seems to be happening only with the home page. Other pages' meta descriptions are in correct language.

Comment: You can specify the url to check in serps?

Comment: What meta tags shows your webmaster and google analytics account?

Comment: I recognised that somehow the cache of the Japanese store top page shows English store. Maybe it is temporary thing, as it happened after I installed "Store / Currency Geo Auto Switcher". Maybe it was indexed wrong somehow. I will wait until the page gets crawled again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was to do with the extension "Store / Currency Geo Auto Switcher".
This issue seems to happen when you have for main store without store code and other stores with code (e.g. mainstore.com , mainstore.com/en/ ).
The solution for this is to add in Auto Switcher setting

"Disabled User Agents"
Group >> google
User Agent RegExp >> /google/i